# How to send data from web app/server to react native app?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am new to React Native and to the whole mobile dev side, to be honest. I am getting involved in a project where we have a web app and we are now creating a react native app that needs to receive a notification if the user interacts with the web app.

Let's say there is a button on the Web App saying `Get Data` and if it's pressed, the React Native App needs to know that something has been requested by the Web App so it could respond with the correct course of action.

I am looking for possible solutions that I should look into. I have been looking into WebSocket and firebase notification services.

I would love to hear from you guys if you have been involved in a similar project or can suggest the best way to approach this.

Comment: Why don't you use API to make network request to server for requested Data?

Comment: I can make the API call to send data to the webserver but I want to receive the notification from the server first before making the call. How does the mobile app know that the webserver has requested data? That's the part I am have not figured out

Comment: Hmm, For this case its better to use Firebase or One Signal (or SocketIO for fully customized solution). For ReactNative, I personally would prefer to go for OneSignal.

Answer (score 2):

You can send invisible push notifications from server side to mobile and in your app you read this invisible notification (some json), then you can identify the type of request, in your case `Get Data`, and from that you can fire a request or run some code.

Check out [One signal](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/react-native-sdk-setup), it's really useful

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Firebase Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/products/realtime-database/) (it's free) to handle that such case. With this service, any client subscribe the node (path) will be notified when the node has any change (add, update, remove), so you do not need to care about server side and concentrate to implement client side. Hope this will help you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use Expo as a beginner it helps you to get started https://expo.io/learn[Expo get started ][1]

[1]: https://expo.io/learn And it have its own tool https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/guides/push-notifications/
it's easy for beginners with the mobile dev side

Comment: Please explain - how does this help the OP?